# C++ singleton and new operator

Tags: c++, class, scope, singleton

Hi I have an snippet of code that is a singleton class ( I believe) that uses 'new' and some other scope and static qualifiers in a way I have not seen before. Because I do not know what it is called I cannot find any information on what it does or its purpose. Code below:

In the myClass.h file I have

```
class myClass
{
private:
    static myClass sm_myClass;
    myClass();
public:
    static void Create(void);
};
```

and in the myClass.cpp I have

```
#include "myClass.h"
#include <new>

myClass* p_myClass = NULL;

myClass myClass::sm_myClass;

myClass::myClass()
{
}

void myClass::Create(void)
{
    p_myClass = &sm_myClass;

    new (p_myClass) myClass();
}
```

My questions are:

1 - What is happening at line 6 ( myClass myClass::sm_myClass; ) of the .cpp file

2 - What is happening at line 16 ( new (p_myClass) myClass(); ) of the .cpp file

3 -  What is the overall purpose of using a class in this way?

I really hope that this question is not a repeat. I searched for an answer for a while but didn't know what terms to even search. Thanks for any help.

Comment: FWIW if you wan to use a singleton see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern

Comment: You might also want to read [What is so bad about singletons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons?rq=1)

Comment: The object `sm_myClass` gets constructed at program startup. The call to placement new attempts to construct a new object on top of the already existing one, giving undefined behavior.

Comment: @PeteBecker: It's actually okay to just placement-new over an existing object, though obviously this is not recommended. IIRC, it's only UB if you relied on the destructor for some side effects.

Comment: @GManNickG -- in limited cases it may be okay, but that's advanced technique, completely inappropriate in a beginner's code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1 - What is happening at line 6 ( myClass myClass::sm_myClass; ) of the .cpp file

A static class member is defined.

> 2 - What is happening at line 16 ( new (p_myClass) myClass(); ) of the .cpp file

A *placement new* is specified to reuse the memory allocated for `p_myClass`

> 3 - What is the overall purpose of using a class in this way?

There are cases when *singletons* might come in handy, but in general it's better to pass interfaces around, instead of tight coupling client code to `myClass`.

---

Don't use `new` (placement `new` or not) to initialize singleton instances. Use the *Scott Meyer's* singleton implementation instead, which guarantees thread safety:

```
class myClass
{
private:
    myClass();
public:
    static myClass& instance() {
         static myClass theInstance;
         return theInstance;
    }
};
```

The instance will be created at first access to the `instance()` function, and stay the same for any subsequent calls.

Comment: Just a precision, this is thread safe only since c++11. It isn't in c++03

Comment: @wasthishelpful Well, I'm concentrating on the current standard, not on elder one's deficiencies.

Comment: Me too :) but we're not everybody ;)

Comment: @wasthishelpful It seems pretty futile to stick for elder standards (says grandpa!).

Answer (score 3):

1) static member variables need to have there storage allocated in one compilation unit (.cpp/.cxx). This definition establishes that.

2) This is called placement new, it allows you to construct an object into already allocated memory. This usage is flawed since the object has already been constructed and that construction is being overwritten.

3) Sometimes it is handy to have a global service encapsulated into an object and having a singleton provides an easy way for clients of that service to get access to it.

Comment: Using the placement new is completely off here, there's no reason to do like so.